# Sticky footer issues, gap above footer

Tags: css, html, footer

I've got an issue where the sticky footer appears to be adding spacing above it, im not sure what is causing this, ive tried a few different sticky footer methods and all seem to have the same issue. 
It must be something wrong with the markup?

here is the site: http://www.adamtoms.co.uk/

Appreciate any help!

Kind Regards,
Adam

```
    <?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head> 
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/mk1/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/mk1/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main">




<div id="container">
<body>

<div id="header" >

  <div id="headleft">
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" />
  </div>

  <div id="headright">
   <div id="navr">
    <div id="nav">
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="breadcrumb">
    <jdoc:include type="module" name="breadcrumb" />
</div><br />



<div id="content">
<jdoc:include type="component" name="content" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="slider" />
</div>


<div id="leftrightmain">
<div id="midleft">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" />
</div>
<div id="midright">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" /></div>
</div>


</body>
</div>


</div>
</div>


<footer>
<div id="footer"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" />
    <jdoc:include type="module" name="debug" />


</footer></div>
</html>
```

Comment: some code might be helpfull if you want any help

Comment: It's not the footer, it's the #main-div. Remove the `padding-bottom: 250px;` - You can use FireBug (for FireFox) or Chrome Developer Tools to deal with such issues.

Comment: thanks i have been using firebug extensivly to try and get past this issue, i cant see to see what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in system.css on line 9 is causing your problem...

```
#main {
   overflow: auto;
   padding-bottom: 250px;
}
```

Make it this:

```
#main {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

I suggest you look into learning how to use a debugging tool like chromes developer tools or firebug for firefox.  This was very easy to find using chromes dev tools, when looking at HTML and hovering your mouse over an element.  It highlights the element itself blue, any padding green and any margin orange.  I highlighted over your footer first and saw now green or orange above the blue highlight indicating it wasn't your footer that had the problem.  So I moved up and I found the div with ID main had a big block of green as I hovered over it indicating a large amount of padding.  I looked at the CSS rules after clicking that div, saw padding: 250px, and unchecked it, and your problem was solved.

**EDIT:**

As NoLiver92 found below...  You definite a -250px margin-top but then you reset it with margin 0 auto...

```
#footer {
position: relative;
background-image:url('../images/bg_footer1.png');
margin-top: -250px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 250px;
clear:both;
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

Make it this instead:

```
#footer {
position: relative;
background-image:url('../images/bg_footer1.png');    
height: 250px;
clear:both;
width: auto;
margin: -250px auto 0 auto;}/* negative value of footer height */
```

Comment: thanks i have updated the css as suggested but the issue is still there :(

Comment: No, it is working now, it just looks to not be working as you don't have enough content.  Throw a couple of paragraphs of dummy text into your body somewhere, anywhere, to force your page to have more height.  Or just re-size your browser window to be really tiny height wise so you can scroll then you'll see it works fine.

Comment: thanks everyone really helpful! I can see it now appers to be working, however you have to scroll down the page to view the footer? why is this scrolling there? I would have thought asthere isnt any content the footer would appear on the page without the need to scroll down?
edit: i have changed the code as sugested, and its working! thank you!! is there a way to remove the side margins around the footer?

Comment: thanks Michael, i have changed the code as sugested, and its working! thank you!! is there a way to remove the side margins around the footer? (remove the white padding either side)

Comment: Put margin: 0 and padding: 0 on your body tag.

Comment: No problem, feel free to contact me if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look here! You give margin top as -250 px but you also set margin to 0 auto. This is a contradiction either delete margin-top or delete margin and replace it with margin-left, margin-right, and margin-bottom.

```
#footer {
position: relative;
background-image:url('../images/bg_footer1.png');
margin-top: -250px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 250px;
clear:both;
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: This is the other half of your problem.  Nice find @NoLiver92.  It should be margin: -250px auto 0 auto; and delete the margin-top